# how do I convert a youtube url to a .wav file?

Tags: c#, url, youtube, converters, wav

I want to know if it is possible to convert a youtube video's url to a .wav file. If it is possible then how can I do this? Thanks and I appreciate all responses.

PS: I'm doing this application in winforms

Comment: I figured you'd like to know: [Youtube's Terms of Service, 5B](http://www.youtube.com/static?gl=US&template=terms) `"You shall not download any Content unless you see a “download” or similar link displayed by YouTube on the Service for that Content."`. But in relation to your topic, there's plenty of online converters out there.

Comment: well nothing really, I tried to do some google research to see where I should start. All I could find was how to convert to other formats so I posted here for help.

Comment: Well, it _is_ possible to do it, since you're asking. But I don't think it's very simple. I'm no expert but I think the order of approach is 1. find a way to fetch the video from the youtube-link. 2. download the video. 3. convert it to .wav. This is really simplified of course, and a lot of it is already done before (especially converting files). I hope this helps.

Comment: ok I got 1. and 2. down now all I need is 3.

Comment: Well, converting is the most complex part. There's a lot of Open Source libraries available to help you with that, to my knowledge, even though I don't know any specific. If you're determined to do it yourself, I think it would be easiest to look into some open source projects first at least - and then, when you have specific programming issues, ask it on StackOverflow, if someone else didn't already.

Comment: yeah I will definitely do that. Right now my skill level is no match for this project so I'll have to leave it for later. I at least know where to start again. Before I completely hold off on this project I'm going to research some alternatives. Thanks again, and to all who posted in this question.

Comment: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to [KeepVid.com](http://www.keepvid.com), punch in the URL of your YouTube video, and save the file you want.

Comment: I know many sites that will convert the video for me but I was hoping to make my own program for myself.

Comment: Got ya. Do you want me to keep this answer here or delete it?

Comment: I think keeping it would be fine, I'm sure there will be people looking for a converter site.